# K-nearest neighbor in python

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, knn

I have data containing a single dimension and a class label. I want to run KNN on it.

My data is something like this

```
feature       Label
0.70436073      1
0.91564351      1
0.9931506       1
2.26418779      0
```

I did the below and ended up in an error. I understand from the error that the data type of train is not recognized, but I have no clue how to fix it. Please help

```
>>> train = [ 0.70436073,  0.91564351,  0.9931506,   2.26418779]
>>> train
[0.70436073, 0.91564351, 0.9931506, 2.26418779]
>>> label = ['1','1','1','0']
>>> from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
>>> knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
>>> knn.fit(train, label)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#26>", line 1, in <module>
    knn.fit(train, label)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\base.py", line 586, in fit
    return self._fit(X)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\base.py", line 126, in _fit
    raise ValueError("data type not understood")
ValueError: data type not understood
```

Answer (score 3):

Well the error message is pretty crap, you should mail those guys and ask them to fix it, but anyway... the example on http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier is pretty clear: the first argument to fit() is a list of lists, not a list of numbers. Furthermore the second argument must be "array of integer values", but you have written an array of strings.

Comment: Thanks, now I get this... `>>> train = [[0.7043607250604991], [0.9156435124135893], [0.9931506043228762], [2.264187785208016]]`
`>>> label = [1,1,1,0]`
`>>> from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier`
`>>> knn = KNeighborsClassifier()`
`>>> knn.fit(train, label)`
`KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, n_neighbors=5, p=2, warn_on_equidistant=True, weights='uniform')`                    but where do we specify which distance metric to be used by the algorithm?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that as I am totally unfamiliar with the algorithm, but have you read the documentation I linked to? It talks quite a bit about distances... If you need more than the documentation I suggest reading the source code: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/tree/master/sklearn/neighbors

Comment: Is there a version of knn available for sequential data?

Answer (score 1):

You first need to use `np.array` to convert your list to an array. Then reshape your array because your data has one feature. Follow this code:

```
import numpy as np
train = np.array([[ 0.70436073,  0.91564351,  0.9931506,   2.26418779]])
train_1 = train.reshape(-1, 1)
label = np.array([['1','1','1','0']])
label_1 = label.reshape(-1,1)
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
knn.fit(train_1, label_1)
```

Comment: According to python [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)... import statements on top of the script. Keep that in mind next time you write or post code like you did now. Alternatively, you can include import statements inside a def (top-side).